# clearing an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear the email input box when `function(data)` is greater than zero. The user will have to be force to re-enter another email address since the form will not submit if any fields are blank. how would I clear out the input box?

**javascript:**

```
$("#email").change(function(){
    var email=$("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"/files/reg_check.php",
        data:"email="+email,
        success:function(data){
            if(data == 0){
                $("#email_msg").html("E-mail Address must be valid");
            } else {
                $("#email_msg").html("<div class='msg_check_red'>Error: E-mail address already in use.</div>");
            }
        }
     });
});
```

**html:**

```
<label>E-mail:</label>
<input type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" id="email" name="add[email]" size="20" title="A valid email address required" class="{validate:{required:true,email:true}}" />
<span class="rsmall"><div id="email_msg">E-mail Address must be valid</div></span><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("#email").val("");`, which sets the value of the input to an empty string.